# React Displaying Undesired Values

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that is displaying `null` or `undefined` shortly before a value is available in the component. I was able to get around this by instead initializing the value as an empty string rather than `null` or `undefined`. I am new to react so there may be a better way to go about this but here is the component:

```
export default function PageHeader(props) {
    return (
        <header>   
            <span>{"AppName"}</span>
            {props.pages.map((page, index) => 
                <span key={index}>{" / " + page}</span>;
            )}
        </header>
    );
}
```

`pages` is an array of values to build a pseudo path (or so we'll call it)

The component is used like so:

```
        <PageHeader 
            pages={["Home"]}
        />
```

The component can accept variables as well

```
        <PageHeader 
            pages={["Blog Posts", variable]}
        />
```

The `variable` would be what is displaying with `null` or `undefined`

Comment: console `variable` at a bunch of different parts in your program, find out where it get's set to it's value

Answer (score 1):

You can do some simple checking like so

```
props.pages.map((page, index) => page ? <span key={index}>{" / " + page}</span> : null)
```

One small note is that it is not recommended to use index as key. Read [document detail](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) for more information

Comment: A check would definitely be acceptable and more desirable than initializing with an empty string

Answer (score 1):

you should check if data exists then run the map function

you can check if every element exists (this will avoid undefined )

```
props?.pages?.map(()=>)
```

or you can put the whole map in a if statement , since it is an array you can use length to see if it is not undefined

```
{props.pages.length? props.pages.map(()=>{}):<div>loading...</div>}
```

and for the variable

i created a sandbox

see  working example

https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-field-nfe17?file=/src/Header.js